# file processing and word sort

Tags: java, parsing, file-processing

Im learning how to look through txt files using java programming, and im wondering why my code is not working. I am using a scanner to take user input, and then using that user input to look through the entirety of Moby Dick, and return the number of occurrences that word has in the book. My only problem is that it returns with 0 no matter what word i put, and i dont know why. I have suspicions that its they way my file is parsing and comparing, but i honestly have no idea. Help is appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MobyDick {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("What word would you like to search for?");
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("mobydick.txt"));
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userWord = userInput.nextLine();
        int wordCount = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()) {    

            String nextWord = input.next();
            
            if (nextWord == userWord) {
               wordCount += 1;

    }
    }
    System.out.println("The total number of " + userWord + "s' in Moby Dick is " + wordCount);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals` to check the equality of `String`. The operator `==` checks the object reference (address of the memory location in heap) in Java and not the actual content of the `String`:

```
if (nextWord.equals(userWord)) {
    wordCount += 1;
}
```